# Enable Mod_Reweite script (Google App Engine)

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, google-app-engine, mod-rewrite

Hey guys im sorry if this has been answered before but I couldn't find an answer. I have a .htaccess, with RewriteEngine On and within that is the rule:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

I want to interpret this rule in mod_rewrite.php which is called in the handler in my app.yaml

mod_rewrite.php:

```
 <?php
 /**
 * @file
 * Provide basic mod_rewrite like functionality.
 *
 * Pass through requests for root php files and forward all other requests to
 * index.php with $_GET['q'] equal to path. The following are examples that
 * demonstrate how a request using mod_rewrite.php will appear to a PHP script.
 *
 * - /install.php: install.php
 * - /update.php?op=info: update.php?op=info
 * - /foo/bar: index.php?q=/foo/bar
 * - /: index.php?q=/
 */

 $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

 // Provide mod_rewrite like functionality. If a php file in the root directory
 // is explicitly requested then load the file, otherwise load index.php and
 // set get variable 'q' to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
 if (dirname($path) == '/' && pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php') {
 $file = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
 }
 else {
 $file = 'index.php';

 // Provide mod_rewrite like functionality by using the path which excludes
 // any other part of the request query (ie. ignores ?foo=bar).
 $_GET['q'] = $path;
 }

// Override the script name to simulate the behavior without mod_rewrite.php.
// Ensure that $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] always begins with a / to be consistent
// with HTTP request and the value that is normally provided.
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/' . $file;
require $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be completely wrong, but wouldn't

```
$path = 'public'.parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
```

be enough?

Also, changing the string of

```
$file = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$file = 'public/index.php';
```

*that is if your index.php is in the public folder, else ignore that last bit.

Comment: When I leave the top line, i get a blank page. But when I do `public/index.php` as you suggested i get the error `Warning: require(../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream:` along with a fatal error. This means it only finds that script but does not invoke see all other ones such as `autoload.php`

Comment: Try dragging the mod_rewrite into your public folder and in the .yaml file change "script: mod_rewrite.php" to "script: public/mod_rewrite.php"

Comment: brilliant that does the trick, but only for the homepage. It started working, however all other URLs aren't working when i click on the navigation.

Comment: What happens when you click on the other links? Does it go back to main page or does it give an error? What the URL that the link directs to?

Comment: the url changes in the browser, but the page stays the same. Im using laravel and composer, my directory structure is MVC based. e.g. views are in `application/view/example_script.php`, modals are in `application/modal/example_script.php` and controllers in `application/controller/example_script.php`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that mod_rewrite tries to include a .php based on the URI, creating a 'makeshift' mod_rewrite. Unfortunately, I'm not too well versed using laravel on gae, so I'd suggest checking these out (http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel-4-on-google-appengine-for-php/ or https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-on-google-app-engine?page=1 , depending on which version your using).

Comment: well this example is supposed to create a mod rewrite to pass through requests for `public/index` using  `$_GET['q']` which i'm not familiar with. Thanks for the links i will have a look though. happy new year!